# Domain of a composition of log functions

Tags: calculus, functions

Domain of $$\log_3(\log_{1/3}(\log_4(\log_{1/4} x)))$$

Please guide me to solve this problem. Since it is a composition of logs, I am confused how to start.

Answer (score 1):

(not gonna discuss complex arguments that might give a real result, because I don't think that's intended in the question)

For the $log_3$ giving something real, the argument has got to be real and $> 0$. Thus

$$\log_{1/3}(\log_{4}(\log_{1/4}(x))) \ \in  \ (0,\infty)$$

which means

$$\log_{4}(\log_{1/4}(x))  \ \in  \ ((1/3)^\infty,(1/3)^0) = (0,1)$$

which is again

$$\log_{1/4}(x)  \ \in  \ (4^0,4^1) = (1,4)$$

and this means

$$x  \ \in  \ ((1/4)^4, (1/4)^1) = (1/256, 1/4).$$

Comment: hmmm, and how can i calculate range???

Comment: @Pratyush By applying the function you gave us to the domain I gave you in my answer.

Comment: thats i understood but i want to know about the range also..kindly explain if you don't mind...

Comment: @Pratyush The domain is $(1/256,1/4)$. All involved logs are either monotonically increasing or decreasing on this interval. Wikipedia says "The composite of two monotone mappings is also monotone", so when we call your entire function $f(x)$, we know it's monotonic. The range is thus between $f(1/256)$ and $f(1/4)$ (check which value is greater).

Comment: Ok it turns out my previous comment was a bit crappy, because your function obviously has singularities at $1/256$ and $1/4$ and is thus unbounded. The composite is monotonically increasing over $(1/256, 1/4)$ and the range is the entire $\mathbb{R}$. Numerically it's hard to figure that out because the function is extreeemly slow close to the boundaries due to the many logs (like, even $f(1/256 + 0.00000001)$ gives a rather small value).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Range+of+logbase3%28logbase%281%2F3%29%28logbase4%28logbase%281%2F4%29+x%29%29%29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20384/discussion-between-pratyush-and-gdumphart).